# Cache write/read times?

Tags: memory, microprocessor, computer-architecture, cache

I would like to devise certain rules of thumb to help solve certain computer design/architecture challenges. Hence, in memory, which operations *typically* take longer to execute: loads or stores?? I think this might help make my choices more realistic during the design process.

Comment: Entirely depends on the processor. I think this question, once more details are added, is a better fit for StackOverflow. You definitely have to make your question more specific, otherwise it might get closed.

Comment: @jippie I think it fits, as computer architectures are part of electrical design, and I've also taken several courses on that.

Comment: Well yes, it does require some more information. But that is exactly why I need to make certain realistic assumptions. In trying to solve a problem in Hennessy and Patterson's book, Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach, I realised it provided very little background info and in trying to solve it differently I need to make and justify assumptions I make.

Answer (score 3):

From an architectural point of view, it depends on which policy your cache uses.

In the **write through** policy, the result of any operation is stored in the cache and in the physical memory in the same cycle; therefore the write operation will take longer, while the read operation will depend on the presence of the data block in the cache.

In the **write back** policy, the result is just stored in the cache and copied in the physical memory only when the same data block is required. Therefore writing and reading can be at the same speed, or either of them can be slower.

[More info.](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/mbsys/cache/func_Write.htm)

Answer (score 3):

This varies widely between architectures.  There is probably no useful rule of thumb.  The technology used in today's memories generally provide for the same read and write time.  This is definitely not true historically, and may not be true again in the future.  For example, core memories are inherently faster to write than read.

Things get more complicated when cache memory is used.  Today, you can probably figure the cache memory has a fixed cycle time whether that is for a read or write.  However, system level considerations change how expensive a read or write is overall.

On a read, some memory someplace has to be physically read and nothing can be done until this result is returned.  If the data is in cache, then it may be available as fast as the processor can make use of it.  If it is not in cache, then something has to saddle up the donkey, trot over to the more distant and slower memory, get a read scheduled, wait for the result, and trot back to the processor with the data.  Note that there can be multiple levels of cacheing with the latency getting a lot longer for more distant levels.  If virtual memory is in use (really just another form of cacheing) and the data is currently swapped out, then the read can be as long as a disk access (or whatever your mass storage device is).

Writes have the advantage that the action can be initiated, but you don't need to wait for it to complete.  This adds complexity however, so not all systems work this way.  Something has to keep track of what hasn't really been written in case a read request comes along before the write process is complete.  The read can then stall or get the value from somewhere partially thru the write process.  There are lots of opportunities for speedups here, but they come at a cost of complexity and additional hardware.  There are therefore lots of different implementations out there.  For example, a write might always guarantee the first level cache is written to before the operation completes or a read can come along.  But then what if all the cache is already occupied with different addresses?  This may require writing a chunk of cache to the next level memory before completing the write into the first level cache.  Again, there are many tradeoffs.

Writes may appear faster immediately because the process can be overlapped with subsequent execution, but they can be more costly overall.  Writing new data to any kind of cache causes that section of the cache to be marked as "dirty".  This means it has to be written to at least the next level of slower memory before it can be re-used to cache a different piece of the global coneptual memory.

Overall, I wouldn't try to guess about writes or reads being faster on a modern high end general purpose computer since lots of fancy cacheing and pre-fetching and overlapped writing could be going on.  The answer is not deterministic and can depend on how long a loop is, what else is going on, and even how the code you care about happens to be aligned in memory.

Fahgeddaboudit.

Comment: A minor advantage of cache reads is that the data array can be accessed in parallel with tags, so the latency of the physical action is less.  (A direct-mapped, write-through, write-allocate cache could, in theory, write in parallel with tag access.)  As noted, the ability to buffer writes tends to take them out of the critical path, so latency of the action itself is less important.

Comment: Reads can also proceed speculatively before an ECC correctness confirmation (this is similar to cache hit speculation) while a write would generally wait for ECC computation to complete in order to perform write of data+ECC at one time.  (Also CAM-based accesses would have equal latency writes.)

Answer (score 3):

"Which takes longer?" is a very vague question, and the answer depends on what you're trying to optimize.

In most cases, when considering the overall performance of a system, you're concerned about stalling the execution pipeline in the CPU. In that sense, loads always take longer that stores, in the sense that stores don't have future operations that depend on them, while loads do.

In other words, with a store operation, you send the address and the data to the memory hierarchy and basically forget about them. However, with a load operation, you send the address and then you need to wait for the data. The compiler and/or hardware scheduler may or may not be able to find useful work to do in the meantime, but there's some nonzero probability that the pipeline will need to stall when it gets to an operation that depends on the data being loaded.

There may be other bottlenecks in the memory hierarchy, depending on the number of levels of cache, their sizes, their access times, their writeback policies, the bandwidths of the busses connecting them, etc. With multiple cores and shared memories, cache synchronization strategy becomes an issue as well. All of these things can potentially create a stall on a load operation.

The only way a store can create a stall is if the write buffers in the memory hierarchy fill up, preventing them from accepting another store from the execution pipeline.

Comment: The question is much simpler. Basically, given a processor core and an L1 cache _only_, how much faster is it to write data from a register to the cache than to read from the cache to a register?